# How can a show a task that has a window for completion

Tags: microsoft-project-2010

I have several tasks within a project that take 2 days but have a three month window in which to complete how do I show this on my gantt chart?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to set a deadline on each task (Task Information window -> Advanced tab). This shows a deadline icon at the appropriate place in the Gantt against each task thus set.

In addition you can set a constraint of "Finish no later than" on the Task Information window -> General Tab

If you want to be very obvious and show an explicit milestone for the deadline then set a milestone task with a "Must Start on [the deadline date]" (auto-scheduled tasks only) and make each relevant task a predecessor of the deadline milestone- that way if any task overruns it will try to push the milestone to the right and you will get a scheduling error.

Any of these can be used singly or together depending on what you need to accomplish.